# Dapp End User Payments in ether

Tags: payments

After reviewing the relative questions. I am not keen enough in this space to discern if these questions and answers address my question. So I will submit my question in a neophyte tenor.

Sell a bundle of pre-programmed ether tokens for a network access and payment, to a vendor subscriber.

The vendor subscriber would then issue a token to their client which uses the ether token to access our network, book an appointment, and pay an network agent.

The ether token should perform three task:

1) Access a network

2) Pay a network transaction fee in ether equal to $2-3.00 USD routed to the network digital wallet

3) Credit a network Agent digital wallet in ether for services provided equal to $20-25.00 USD

Theoretically how much gas may be required to validate this block?

How much gas is required to credit the network's digital wallet with the transaction fee of ether payment equal to $2-3.00 USD.

How much gas is required to convert the for the network to connect with an ethereum exchange for the highest value and deposit the fiat in USD to the networks bank account?

How much gas is required to do the following? How can a network Agent connect to an exchange and convert ether payment in their digital wallet to $20-25.00 USD fiat and be routed to the Agent bank account?

To me this seems like a lot of smart contract activity however what is the answers? Please help. Thank you in advance.